# How can I protect my tron deck against Crumble To Dust

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

So I made a really cool Mono-Black Eldrazi Tron deck. The only decks it has lost to are Bogles and an Izzet Control that was running a few copies of [Crumble to Dust](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crumble%20to%20Dust). The only thing I can come up with for [Crumble to Dust](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crumble%20to%20Dust) is [Memoricide](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Memoricide) and/or [Cranial Extraction](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cranial%20Extraction). Does anyone know another or better way? And what could I do about Bogles?

Comment: What are they targeting with Crumble to Dust that it derails your deck sufficiently to build against it?

Comment: I'm guessing any of the urza lands. Without a complete set, each land is only going to generate (C). This properly leaves the tron player with 7+ CMC spells in hand that they are going to have to wait until at least turn 7 until they can start playing threats (rather than the planed turn 3/4). By this time, it is probably too late and may even by dead.

Comment: @DrunkCynic It depends. If he plays Eye of Ugin, you target that. If he plays Eldrazi Temple, you target that. If he assembles Tron, you target Urza's Tower. It's a pretty flexible card against Eldrazi (even more so against the Eldrazi Tron version). Evan Burnett took three of them to [tenth place at an SCG event](http://sales.starcitygames.com//deckdatabase/displaydeck.php?DeckID=99329) a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: @ProgenitorMimic I assumed such, assumptions just don't sit well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could go with regular black hand disruption like [Thoughtseize](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thoughtseize) or [Duress](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Duress) then maybe have some [Surgical Extraction](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Surgical%20Extraction) to clean them up after that.

For Bogles, making the player sacrifice a creature would be good. [Cruel Edict](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cruel%20Edict) or [Devour Flesh](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Devour%20Flesh) or [Geth's Verdict](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Geth%27s%20Verdict) are some low-mana options. You could go for a bomb with [Liliana of the Veil](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Liliana%20of%20the%20Veil)

What's good about the hand disruption is that it's just good in general, against most decks, and might even be in you main deck. The creature sacrificing is a bit more situational, but for decks that ramp w/o mana dorks, or bogles it'd be good to have in the sideboard.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I didn't come up with Thoughtseize. Duh. I was in tunnel vision going... I want to destroy EVERY Crumble to Dust!! lol. And yes the sacrificing will work great in the SB.

Comment: @thatdude1087 Well if they're going to take away all your lands, it's only fair!

Answer (score 6):

Since [Crumble to Dust](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crumble%20to%20Dust) is a sorcery, you could use the card [Warping Wail](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Warping%20Wail) to counter it. Warping Wail has some other utility and it requiring a colorless mana should be no problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

It costs four mana. Just kill them before they cast it. Or, in black (and colorless, with [Though-Knot Seer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Though-Knot%20Seer)), use targeted discard to take it out of their hand, and then kill them before they draw another. You want some sort of targeted discard to deal with sweepers and such anyways, so this doesn't even have to cost a slot.

Land destruction spells don't actually do anything to protect against threats you have already resolved. It's disrupting spells that you *might* play later. So the solution is to punish them for spending an entire turn's worth of mana to kill your land, by hitting them with the threats you already have out.

Against Boggles, any sort of removal that doesn't target will work. [Damnation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Damnation), [Cruel Edict](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cruel%20Edict), [Infest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Infest), [Ratchet Bomb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ratchet%20Bomb), etc...

Comment: -1 because the first paragraph won't work. Tron is a slow deck. You can't expect to kill people before they reach 4 mana.

Comment: It kind of reads like you don't know how Tron works. Tron relies on having a lot of mana to cast big things, it gets this mana from the Urza lands. Because Tron is meant to rely on a lot of mana, it's slow, you aren't going to "Kill them before they can cast it" so paragraph 1 is out. Losing one of the Urza lands can be recovered from, losing all copies of one of the lands probably can't since it completely shuts down Tron's mana base, so paragraph 2 is out.